# HP LaserJet 4L is not working

Tags: 10.10, printing, hp

After I have Installed Ubuntu 10.10 my printer is not working anymore. My printer is connected through a parallel port. I was told that the cups have changed in Maverick. Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add if it was working before? Did you do an upgrade, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I noticed in (System → Administration → Printing> Policies) that I needed to put a check mark by "Enabled" "Accepting jobs" and "Shared".

Comment: @Daniel Can you mark Eric's answer as accepted?

Comment: Problem Solved.